# Is is possible to suppress 'ans' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a function, but I do not want the `ans = ...` in the end. Is it possible to suppress it?

For instance:

```
function c = Example (b)
c = b + 2;
end
```

On the command window:

```
>>Example (8)
>>ans = 10
```

Comment: `Example(8);`, exactly what the answer below says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a semicolon at the end of the line where the function is called. Here's the bit of documentation that covers this.

From the [symbol reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-46):

> **Output Suppression**
>
> When placed at the end of a command, the semicolon tells MATLAB not to display any output from that command. In this example, MATLAB does not display the resulting 100-by-100 matrix:
>
> ```
> A = ones(100, 100);
> ```

This pertains to display.  AFAIK, there's no way to prevent MATLAB from still assigning to `ans` (i.e. `rand;` still assigns the result to `ans`).

Comment: Actually no, that does not work for functions...

Comment: @Michelle Sorry I misunderstood.  Please show an example. (not my downvote by the way).

Comment: `Example(8);` will suppress display of `ans = ...`.

Comment: Oh so simple.. You were right all along! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Further to @chappjc's answer, it *is* possible to suppress the creation of `ans` - but it may not be all that desirable. The trick is to assign the outputs only if `nargout` is non-zero. For example:

```
function varargout = Example(b)
     c = b + 2;
     if nargout > 0
         varargout = {c};
     end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking without modifying the called function, but this is a good point.